# Is it possible to run angular commands from package manager console?

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I have created the angular project in visual studio 2019, now can i run angular command such as `ng g c bank-account` in package manager console.or there is any other way to do it in visual studio

Comment: What do you mean by package manager console? Are you referring to the terminal? Do you want to use an UI console instead of the terminal?

Comment: @ionut-t how can I use the terminal in visual studio? kindly help me with that

Comment: I don't use Visual Studio but I think this article can help you https://www.hanselman.com/blog/VisualStudioNowIncludesAnIntegratedTerminal.aspx

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This should show you terminal. and yes you can run ng commands.

Comment: this is visual studio code and i was talking about visual studio 2019

Comment: Go here :- https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/say-hello-to-the-new-visual-studio-terminal/